# Magento 2: Not Allow to Rest Estimate Shipping and Tax value on qty change in checkout/cart/ page

Tags: magento2, cart

After Adding a product into the cart I go to checkout cart page and fill the Estimate Shipping and Tax data it is set fine. after that I refresh the page and again check Estimate Shipping and Tax data it is same as which is I set.

Now I Change the Qty of that product in the cart and hit the update button after page load successfully again, I check Estimate Shipping and Tax from data which is reset.

So how to prevent rest Estimate Shipping and Tax from data on Qty update.

Answer (score 0):

please add below code with which is working qty update

```
define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData, quote, defaultProcessor, customerAddressProcessor, rateRegistry) {
                 /* Minicart reloading */
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                var processors = [];

                rateRegistry.set(quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey(), null);
                
                processors.default =  defaultProcessor;
                processors['customer-address'] = customerAddressProcessor;

                var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();

                if (processors[type]) {
                    processors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
                } else {
                    processors.default.getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
                }
});
```

try to use above code, its working for me...